# Data distribution in hadoop framework

Tags: hadoop

Good day everybody,

Please i am new to hadoop and I have this question, does hadoop allows task parallelism only (I.e distribute the same dataset in multiple nodes and then run the task in parallel)

Thanks

Comment: Not at all - the dataset is split to blocks which distribute across data nodes. Every block *can* be replicated in multiple nodes.

Comment: @shay thanks a lot. please do you have any suggestion for a better framework to handle this. thanks